# Class design:class implementing an Interface implementing another interface

Tags: java, class-design

I have one interface MLService which has basic methods related to training and cross validation of a Machine Learning Algorithm, I have to add two more interface classify and predict which will implement MLService and contain methods either to classify and get one feature or predict probability of multiple features depending upon my algo, the specific implementaion methods in the class implementing either classify or predict have to be called from MLService object.. how should this be designed to achieve the specified functionality?

Comment: Prior to Java 8, interfaces do not contain algorithms and are therefore unable to "call" code.

Comment: Even in Java 8 interfaces should not contain algorithms. But there are rare cases to make exception from that rule. E.g. to maintain backwards compatibility of your API. As the JDK does it for supporting functional features.

Comment: @Smutje : my concern here is that a reference of MLService interface be able to call a method a defined in let's say classify interface(which extends MLService) and implemented in a class(let's say SVMServiceImpl which implements classify interface ).. i want to achieve this in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your example in comment, you can use Object TypeCasting to call method of another(Child) interface

```
public class SVMServiceImpl implements Classify,AnotherInterface{


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        MLService mlserv = new SVMServiceImpl();
        /**
         * Your Algo-based on this below's typecasting should happen
         */
        ((Classify)mlserv).classifyMethod();//or ((AnotherInterface)mlserv).anotherMethod();

    }
}
```